# trato de hacer codigo aleatorio de 10 caracters alfanumericos en C, pero no me imprime bien el array que muestra el codigo

Tags: c

el array "lista" es la ,lista de donde quiero coger caracters aleatorios y el array "identificador" es donde quiero colocar estos caracteres aleatorios.

```
#include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "time.h"
    

int main(void){
    
        char lista[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        char identificador[10];
        int j=rand() % 37;
        int i;
        srand(time(NULL));
    
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    
            identificador[j]=lista[j];
        }
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            printf("%d", lista[i]);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Segun lo que entiendo quieres copiar caracteres aleatorios al array llamado `identificador` pero no estas copiando 10 caracteres en el primer bucle sino literalmente estas copiando el mismo character 10 veces. Otro problema es donde imprimes. Quieres imprimir la `identificador` o `lista`?

Comment: acabo de averiguarlo muchas gracias mi fallo era que estaba diciendo que me llevase al caracter aleatorio de lista a una posicion aleatoria de identificador cuando tenia que señalar la posicion 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estos son los errores que vi en tu código:

- Los números de `lista[]` deberían ser también strings para que se
  puedan concatenar:

---

```
char lista[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
```

- Tal como te mencionan en los comentarios, no estás copiando los 10 caracteres aleatorios en el primer bucle. Lo que deberías hacer es que la operación `rand() & 37` esté en cada bucle y almacenarlo en `identificador[i]` para que en el segundo `for` llames a `identificador[i]`, mostrando éste los 10 caracteres alfanuméricos. Tu bucle `for` tendría que estar de la siguiente forma:

---

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  int j = rand() % 37;
  identificador[i] = lista[j];
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  printf("%c", identificador[i]);
}
```

---

Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    char lista[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char identificador[10];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int j = rand() % 37;
        identificador[i] = lista[j];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", identificador[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// 1ifeo0nfnu
// 3nlll1lq6m
```

Answer (score 0):

No es lo mismo un número que un carácter.

Los primeros son valores que se guardan tal cual en la memoria del equipo, mientras que para los segundos, lo que se almacenan son unos valores que no son sino unos índices que permiten localizar caracteres concretos en una tabla de caracteres.

Así, no es lo mismo el número 5 que el caracter `'5'`. El primero se representa con el valor 0x05 mientras que el segundo con el valor 0x35.

Lo que tienes que hacer, es convertir los números en caracteres:

```
char lista[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
```

Luego date cuenta que no es lo mismo un caracter que una cadena de caracteres... si te das cuenta, las letras las estás almacenando cono cadenas de caracteres, no como caracteres.

Ten en cuenta que una cadena de caracteres es realmente un puntero que apunta a la posición de memoria donde se almacena la secuencia de caracteres... los cuales terminan con el caracter nulo...

Lo dicho, reemplaza las comillas dobles por comillas simples.

Para terminar, al printf le tienes que decir que quieres imprimir caracteres, no números:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%c", lista[i]);
```